# How to stop force-directed graph simulation

Tags: graph, d3.js

I'm trying to use D3 for HTML presentation of directed graph, by reusing this well-known example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

I have a data with 5K nodes, and 20K edges.

Problem is that when I load the page, it never seems to finish partitioning (or whatever else is doing with the data), so I can't wait to see complete result.

Is there any way I can stop the simulation?
For example, after ~20 seconds, network graph is well partitioned and I would like it to stop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop a d3 force graph layout simulation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112108/how-to-stop-a-d3-force-graph-layout-simulation)

Answer (score 3):

```
simulation.stop()
```

Stops the simulation’s internal timer, if it is running, and returns the simulation. If the timer is already stopped, this method does nothing. This method is useful for running the simulation manually;

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I have done it.

```
const simulationDurationInMs = 20000; // 20 seconds

let startTime = Date.now();
let endTime = startTime + simulationDurationInMs;

let simulation = d3.forceSimulation() 
    /*snip - set up your simulation*/
    .on("tick", onSimulationTick);

function onSimulationTick() {
    if (Date.now() < endTime) {
        /*update the simulation*/
    } else {
        simulation.stop();
    }
}
```