# Drag not working correctly after node transition, D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a force network something similar to this :

http://jsfiddle.net/Brb29/7/

On the button press i translate the nodes to the same position :

```
function positionnodes(){

     force.stop();
     nodes.each(function(d){
         d.fixed = true;
         d.x = 100;
         d.y = 100;
     }).transition().duration(1000).attr("transform", function(d)
    {

    //console.log(d.hasRelationship);
    //console.log(d.y);
    return "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"; 

    });

    edges.transition().duration(1000).attr("x1", function (d) {

        console.log(d.source.x)
        return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function (d) {console.log(d.source.y)
        return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function (d) {console.log(d.target.x)

        return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function (d) {console.log(d.target.y)
        return d.target.y;
    });
    //setTimeout(function(){ force.start();},1000);

}
```

My problem is, after i do this and i go to drag the nodes, the node position jumps back to its previous even though i have set it. It's as if the d.x/d.y hasn't updated.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Its just the force gravity doing its job... But it's not necessarily the same spot. If you drag a node so that the triangle of nodes rotates for example,  and then release it, it will return to the center but stay rotated.

Comment: did you click the button ? try this updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Brb29/7/

Comment: Yes I did and I tried your new version... My previous comment still applies. Try setting gravity to zero and setting initial x and y values for the nodes ( so they don't go screaming off the page and never come back).

Comment: That's not my problem though. My problem is after I click the button then try to move one of the nodes the ones i dont click seem to move back to a previous position and not stay where i put them. I dont think it has anything to do with the gravity

Comment: I don't think != I don't know. Try it.

Comment: You mean you know ? If you do, could you try edit the fiddle to show me ?It would be appreciated :)

Comment: It's your project dude... You don't know how to do those edits? Happy to help if you don't...

Comment: i know its my project lol but changing the gravity wont do anything if the nodes position is different to what i set it to be.

Comment: It's the gravity that is bringing it back to the same, or similar position. The default gravity will always bring the nodes back to the centre of the graph. If you switch it off and set an initial position for the nodes like I suggested, then you will see that the node does not return to its original position after you drag it.

Comment: i stopped the force, force.stop() so this should stop the whole movement but it doesnt work.Ive even added this line : setTimeout(function(){ force.gravity(0).start();},1000); so the gravity is set to 0 after one second and starting the force layout. this doesn't work. Like ive said would be appreciated if you showed me what you mean as i dont think that is the answer

Comment: force.drag will trigger force.start. So locations of each circle will be re-computed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drag event will trigger force.start and then (x,y) of all nodes will be re-computed. To avoid triggering force.start, you need overwrite the event handler for force.drag, see 
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112108/how-to-stop-a-d3-force-graph-layout-simulation)

OK. Here is a working example: [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Brb29/8/). The core part is here:

```
var drag = force.drag()
                .origin(function(d) {
                    var t = 
d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")).translate;
                    return {x: t[0], y: t[1]};
                })
                .on("drag.force", function(d) {
                    var cord = [0,0];
                    cord = d3.mouse(this);
                    d.x = cord[0];
                    d.y = cord[1];
                    tick();
                });
```

Comment: great stuff. Someone who knows what the problem is. Appreciate the answer :))))

Comment: one thing. when testing your solution, as soon as i run it, i drag the blue one and it drags the orange and green one instead. Any ideas ?

Comment: Initially, you call force.drag. After you clicked the button, you use the customized force.drag event handler.